# How do I pass a list through a function and save the output for each set of inputs in the list

Tags: r

So, let's say I have the following data set:

```
    X   N   A   B     C
1   5   1   1   0.1   0.1
2   10  1   1   0.1   0.2
3   15  1   2   0.2   0.4
4   20  1   3   0.3   0.8
5   25  2   5   0.5   1.6
6   30  2   8   0.8   3.2
7   35  2   13  1.3   6.4
8   40  2   21  2.1   12.8
9   45  3   34  3.4   25.6
10  50  3   55  5.5   51.2
11  55  3   89  8.9   102.4
12  60  3   144 14.4  204.8
```

And I have two functions. One of them creates a new data frame from the above:

```
funcd<- function(s, n) {
d=data[data$N==n,]
d2<-data.frame(d$X)
d2$N<-d$N; d2[[s]]<-d[[s]]
d2
}
```

where for 's' you put in one of column headers, and 'n' one of the values from columns N. For example:

```
>funcd("A", 1)
  d.X N A
1   5 1 1
2  10 1 1
3  15 1 2
4  20 1 3
```

Basically, it makes a new data frame out of one of the columns from the old one (either A, B, or C) and, within the selected column, only the rows that have N=n (in the example, 1, 2, or 3). It retains the 'X' and 'N' columns from the original data frame too.

My second function makes a plot of the aforementioned whichever column was used to make the second data (whatever is put in as 's') against the values in column X in the rows for whatever value of 'n' is put in.

```
funcp<-  function(s, n) {
d=data[data$N==n,]
d2<-data.frame(d$X)
d2$N<-d$N; d2[[s]]<-d[[s]]
plot(d2$d.X, d2[[s]])
}
```

So funcp("A", 1) gives a simple plot of column A against column d.X from my example above of funcd("A", a)

Now what I want to do is save the data sets from funcd output as txt files, and the plots from funcp as png files, which I know I can do manually for each individual set of inputs with:

```
write.table(funcd("A", 1), "C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\data.txt")
```

and

```
png(filename="C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\plot.png")
funcp("A", 1)
dev.off()
```

respectively. But let's say I need text files and a plots for my functions for each of the following inputs: ("A", 1), ("B", 2), and ("C", 3). How could I automatically create files for the output of my functions for each of those inputs without having to manually save them for each individual input? Suffice it to say, for my actual data set, it is not just A, B, and C, but a few hundred columns, as is also the case for my values for 'N'. So I want to make a script that can make image files from the plots (or text files from the data frames) for the outputs of the function for each set of inputs in a list, the list being something like (("A", 1"), ("B", 2)...).

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to what part you're asking about, but if you just want to create unique file names, then

```
s<-"A"; n<-1
png(filename=paste("C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\plot.", s, ".", m, ".png", sep="")
funcp(s, n)
dev.off()
```

will give you a different file name for each png.

Bust if you want to iterate over all combinations of s/n, you can do

```
expand.grid(s=c("A","B","C"), n=1:3)
```

And you can feed those results to mapply if you like

```
mm<-expand.grid(s=c("A","B","C"), n=1:3)
mapply(funcp, mm$s, mm$n)
```

Comment: I don't necessarily need to iterate over every combination. I guess I forgot to specify, I would like to iterate over a specific list (specific columns actually correspond to values of n, so (A, 1), (B, 2), (C, 3) and so on are the only combinations I need. But for each iteration, I want to create a file for the resultant output/plot. Basically to avoid having to run funcp("A", 1), then export plot; run funcp("B," 2), then export plot, run func("C", 3), then export, and on and on and on.

Comment: @user3593717 So just put the `png()` and `dev.off()` inside `funcp()` and build the file name dynamically as I suggested.